# Running Live with 4GB RAM. 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, live-usb, live-cd, ram, 32-bit

I have a laptop with 4GB RAM and it is fully 64-bit capable.
However I prefer to run Ubuntu from Live CD or USB. This takes 2GB of the RAM as the main drive. Does that leave me with 2GB of RAM? Because when I open System Monitor it shows 3.9GB available RAM (as it would if it was a normal installation).
If I actually have 2GB of available RAM should I use the 32-bit or 64-bit version when running Live CD?
I don't know if its relevant but when running 64-bit live, if I open too many tabs on Google Chrome, the Live session freezes completely.

Comment: booting the LIVE system does *not* load everything into RAM.  you need to leave the LIVE media in place.

Comment: start a terminal and run `top`.   open a tab and check the top display.  repeat another tab and check.

Comment: get more RAM.  64-bit works fine in 4GB. i run 64-bit in 1GB on 3 of my servers.

Comment: @Skaperen Yes I leave the media in place. I meant to ask which version is _better_ for me, given the fact that only 2GB of RAM is available when running Live (right?)